# SUMIF but ignore rows hidden by filter

Tags: excel, vba, hidden

I have this simple formula that gets the sum of a column if the adjacent column is ="unpaid"

```
=SUMIF(workdays[Status], "=Unpaid", workdays[Earned Pay])
```

How do I change it to work only on rows hidden by a filter in my table?
 Explanations would be great.